# Facebook Ograph plugin reaps sporadic results

Tags: wordpress, facebook, image, facebook-opengraph

Plugin: [Facebook Open Graph, Google+ and Twitter Card Tags](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/)

Purpose: The plugin is supposed to provide ograph tags around your posted content. The options set should first point to the ograph image specified in the plugin's added image field. If not found, then the featured image. If not found then the default image (blank.gif for test purposes).

Issue: Sporadic results. Sometimes the ograph image specified appears (after several FB Debugger scrapes. Other times the default image appears.

In all test cases, the suggested image size of 1200x630 px in JPG format was specified in the plugins ograph image field.

FB Open Graph Object Debugger provides me with this: 
*

> The app (my app id) specified in fb:app_id meta tag is not published
>   yet. App attribution will be disabled when shared stories are
>   rendered. Please check the status in the app settings.

*

The FB App ID is specified in the plugin config. True, the FB App Id is not submitted to be published.

Would we need to publish the FB App ID? Not sure since we really aren't developing an app.  If we must publish, which screens would I supply?

The domain's DNS is set up with an A record, not a CName. Some research suggests only CName will work - but no mention of that on FB documentation.

**Test results:**

GOOD

Military test for URL:  wels(DOT)net/dev-military/heavenly-math/

BAD

Daily Dev test for URL: wels(DOT)net/dev-daily/20160608/

:) Once I get a solution, how do I get the entire site scraped if I have more than 3000 pages?

*Note: Plugin author speaks another language and is inactive on his forum.*

Ref.

Comment: Your second URL, `wels.net/dev-military/dev-daily/20160608/`, only gives a 404. Does this mean you removed it, because the problem is solved already?

Comment: My bad - a copy / paste error on top of the other URL. Here is the correct URL: wels.net/dev-daily/20160608/

Comment: According to the “See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL” link in the debug tool, that seems to deliver different OG meta values when requested by Facebook - og:image is `http://wels.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/BlankKeep-1.gif` according to debug tool, whereas when I request the URL in my browser and check the tags, it is `http://wels.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Og1200x630-WednesdayDevotion.jpg` I’d suspect that there’s maybe some client-dependent caching going on in your system.

Comment: So our site has object cache (which i have emptied numerous times - with no change) and Varnish cache which I have no control over.

Comment: Any other steps I might take?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! The permalink structure on our site is domain/postname  However, what has been entered into the permalink field (to make each post unique) was domain/post-type/date manually.  Post-type is also the archive link.

Since Wordpress permalink structure is domain/postname... the postname MUST be unique. As soon as I added a prefix to the date, Facebook was able to grab the ograph.

Example:
BAD - domain/post-type/date
GOOD - domain/post-type/prefix-date

Why? Because we have multiple CPT's and they were all using date as the postname. Facebook didn't know how to resolve even though they were valid URLs.